# Is it appropriate for a manager to apportion the recruitment to everyone in a team?

Tags: management, recruitment, referral

My boss told us in a weekly meeting that he will expand hiring but felt very hard to find good employees. And he said he preferred internal referrals since the employees we referred performed very well and we were in a good position to suggest a good fit. He encouraged all of us to refer our ex-colleagues or friends to him by sending him a private message.

I agree with the policy and in fact, I introduced one of my ex-colleagues to HR last year and have got the referral bonus, but what he said next upset me. He apportioned the recruitment task to each one of us, saying that all of us should refer at least one candidate who was available for a job interview within a certain period of time.

I don't know anyone who would likely jump ship to a new job now, then what should I do to deal with that? Is it appropriate for a manager to apportion the recruitment to everyone in a team?

Comment: What country are you from? Do you have a document that outlines your job description?

Comment: @GregoryCurrie You are right. I sent him a message saying that I don't know anyone who is looking for an opportunity and I will let you know if I know in the future just now.

Comment: I asked two questions (how can I be right?). Can you please answer the questions.

Comment: That's a really misguided policy, and is going to end up with your boss/etc wasting a lot of time interviewing people who are at best just doing a practice interview for a friend and have no interest in actually changing jobs.

Comment: @Weiterbildung: Do you have a LinkedIn, Facebook, Twitter or social account ? You can probably post a message on those accounts saying that your company is hiring and ask your friends to refer their friends or co-workers who are looking for work. Due to COVID-19, a lot of people are looking for work. Furthermore, if you mention that you are willing to share part of the referral money with them, it will work perfectly well. :-)

Comment: @Job_September_2020 Yes, but I don't like posting such messages.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie It's not in my job description.

Comment: "It's not in my job description." That's the real underlying problem. Isn't it? If you don't like the way your boss is forcing you to do this, just make a bad referral.

Comment: So either your boss writes poor adverts or won’t pay to advertise in good places. That’s his job. All you need to do is to refer a friend who may not be prepared to change, for whatever reason...

Answer (score 5):

Just tell your boss you have asked around but haven't found anyone suitable. It's not like he can penalise you for it.

Comment: Or refer a friend who is absolutely the best match who is on a much higher salary :) May make the boss think - probably not on second thoughts...

Comment: @SolarMike I wouldn't even ask around, I got better things to do, just fob the boss off with that.

Comment: I have seen bosses do that, but like this : "If you know anyone who is looking for work or a change and is experienced with X or Y, please let me know". And seen it work well, but no forcing...

Comment: Yeah I have seen bosses do it that way. Demands to do recruiting is out of line though.

Comment: " It's not like he can penalise you for it." If the OP is in America, can't he generally just be fired on the spot, for no good reason?

Comment: @GregoryCurrie yep, but it's not a reasonable thing to sack someone for when you're looking for more staff, not less.